# Need a button for catalog input type on add attribute page in magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

i created a text field attribute for gift coupon.need a button named "generate" near to it, used to populate the text field with a unique coupon code on the click of that button.
searched a lot but nothing got.

updated my code on

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @see Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element
 */
?>
<?php $_element = $this->getElement() ?>
<?php $this->checkFieldDisable() ?>
<?php
    $elementToggleCode = $_element->getToggleCode() ? $_element->getToggleCode()
        : 'toggleValueElements(this, this.parentNode.parentNode)';
?>

<?php if ($_element->getType()=='hidden'): ?>
<tr>
    <td class="hidden" colspan="100"><?php echo trim($_element->getElementHtml()) ?></td>
</tr>
<?php else: ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><?php echo trim($this->getElementLabelHtml()) ?></td>
    <td class="value">
        <?php echo trim($this->getElementHtml()) ?>
        <?php if ($_element->getNote()) : ?>
            <p class="note"><?php echo $_element->getNote() ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="scope-label"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->getScopeLabel() ?></span></td>
    <?php if ($this->canDisplayUseDefault()): ?>
    <td class="value use-default">
        <input <?php if($_element->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> type="checkbox" name="use_default[]" id="<?php echo $_element->getHtmlId() ?>_default"<?php if ($this->usedDefault()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="<?php echo $elementToggleCode; ?>" value="<?php echo $this->getAttributeCode() ?>"/>
        <label for="<?php echo $_element->getHtmlId() ?>_default" class="normal"><?php echo $this->__('Use Default Value') ?></label>

    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
**<?php
if($_element->getId()=='giftcoupen'){
  //modify here to have your button
?>
<input type="submit" name="gen" value="Generate" />
<?php
}
?>**
```

---

Then i get a generate button after this .but while clicking on it goes to submit action. i don't have the idea how to make it work to generate the coupon code .

---

[image: screen shot of my page]

Comment: "Input type" can't be a button

Comment: oops :( ....but  i need a button on the product add page...how can i do that ??? please help

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the button?

Comment: i created a text field attribute for gift coupon.need a button named "generate" near to it, used to populate the text field with a unique coupon code

Comment: And update your question with more information as you added as comment

Comment: @DushyantJoshi as you said. updated my question and the code .after that i got the generate button but don't have any idea,how to achieve my target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can achieve this by modifying the following template file

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml

```
if($_element->getId()=='your_attribute_code'){
  //modify here to have your button
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot i tried something in my code and working properly now ...thank you <3

Comment: And it is always better to override the functionality to make it upgrade safe. The class might be I think Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element